Are there 12 interaction mechanisms between photons and matter?
According to this textbook, Physics for Clinical Oncology, p.24:

There are thought to be up to twelve ways in which photons interact with matter of which only three are of relevance to the radiation oncologist.

It goes on to say the three common ones are the photoelectric effect, Compton scattering and pair production.
Can anyone point me to an authoritative reference on this claim there are twelve?

I think most people who have studied QED would say that there is only one such interaction (or “vertex”), which is involved in a variety of different processes.

I guess it the number refers to some subdivision of different manifestations of QED phenomena/effects. E.g., van der Waals forces are just a particular manifestation of electromagnetism. I guess they do not tell you what the other 9 ways are?

I second Lukas' guess on this, it's likely some lower level subdividing of different phenomenon, and hence the QFT tag is probably far too much detail for this question....but that's guesswork on our side for the authors intentions if they didn't specify.

Yeah I now realize this...
I was naively hoping for some nice bright-line answer like QFT is the theory, these are the twelve Feynman diagrams or whatever, there you go.
Even reading up at my level from wiki, take Thomson and Compton scattering: are they really different interactions or same one as viewed through different theoretical frameworks?
Wonder if they mean something like: photo-electric, Compton, pair production, triplet production, photodisintegration (neutron, proton, alpha varieties?), photofission.
And then back down to classical: Rayleigh scattering, Mie scattering...

And refraction, diffraction, reflection, absorption, emission, 3 scattering mechanisms, interference, stimulated emission,  ..... in addition to the above.
